# React - event.target.id no getting id from element

Tags: reactjs, event-handling

I'm trying to get the id from the element and then update it's state to the new id value.

The function where I handle the update:

```
updateID = (e) => {
    console.log("IDFEEDING::" + this.state.id.feeding);
    const { id, name } = e.target;
    console.log("HereID::" + id + "," + name);
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      const updatedID = {
        ...prevState.id,
        [name]: id
      };
      return {
        id: updatedID
      }
    })
  }
```

and here the element where I call the function to update the values. Update values works, but id no.. doesn't gives me erros, it's just doesn't update, I can't get the new id when I select a new radio button.

```
<RadioGroup id={this.state.id.feeding} aria-label="quiz" name="feeding" value={this.state.group.feeding}
                onChange={(event) => {
                  var group = { ...this.state.group };
                  group.feeding = event.target.value;
                  this.setState({ group });
                  this.updateTotal(event)

                  var id = { ...this.state.id };
                  id.feeding = event.target.id;
                  this.setState({ id });
                  this.updateID(event)
                }}>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

**setState is async**, so it won't update the value immediately. You would need to make use of callback approach.

Also since you are executing many things within the onClick handler, I recommend you take it out into new function

```js
updateID = ({ id, name }) => {
    console.log("IDFEEDING::" + this.state.id.feeding);
    console.log("HereID::" + id + "," + name);
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      const updatedID = {
        ...prevState.id,
        [name]: id
      };
      return {
        id: updatedID
      }
    })
  }
onChange= (event) => {
    var group = { ...this.state.group };
    const {id, value, name } = event.target;
    group.feeding = value;

    var id = { ...this.state.id };
    id.feeding = id;
    // Use one setState instance to update both
    this.setState({ id, group }, () => {
      // using on callback
      this.updateTotal(group);
      this.updateID({id, name})
    });
  }
}
...
<RadioGroup id={this.state.id.feeding} aria-label="quiz" name="feeding" value={this.state.group.feeding}
                onChange={this.onChange}>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but still can't get the ID.. i'm trying to get the ID and then update, but it doesn't get..